# Bootstrap 3 does not collapse navbar on mobile or tablet size

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make the navbar collapsible but for some reason it collapse and close its self very fast.
Here is my code:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                <img class="logo" src="../img/logo.png" /></a>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="../Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Library/Library.aspx">Library</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../About.aspx">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                            <AnonymousTemplate>
                                <a href="#login" id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" data-toggle="modal">Log In</a>
                            </AnonymousTemplate>
                            <LoggedInTemplate>
                                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Accounts</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/" /></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </LoggedInTemplate>
                        </asp:LoginView>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can someone tell me whats the problem with it?

Comment: It's working fine.If it's still a problem for you, can you add a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your "button" to a "div" tag this will prevent a post back from happening.